# ruby string interpolation issue with net/imap library

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby's built-in imap/net library. There seems to be an issue with string interpolation. The following works fine:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com',993, true)
imap.login('myuser@gmail.com','password')    
imap.select('INBOX')
ids = imap.search(["SINCE", "26-Sep-2016"])
 => [1, 2]
```

I used a string literal above. However, when I replace the string literal with the following, an error occurs:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com',993, true)
imap.login('myuser@gmail.com','password')    
imap.select('INBOX')
ids = imap.search(["SINCE", Time.now.strftime('%d-%b-%y')])
 => Net::IMAP::BadResponseError: Could not parse command
```

What does only a string literal work when the result of Time.now.strftime is a string literal? This is a standard library in ruby, so for sure it must work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%y` in [`Time#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) is the 2-digit year, and [`Net::IMAP#search` requires a 4-digit year](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-search). You want `%Y`:

```
Time.now.strftime('%d-%b-%y') # => "28-Sep-16"
Time.now.strftime('%d-%b-%Y') # => "28-Sep-2016"
```

This isn't just a requirement of Net::IMAP, it's actually [defined by the IMAP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-84) on pages 84 and 85.